# Detox react-native build success, "Detox can't seem to connect to the test app(s)!" (iOS)

Tags: react-native, detox

Managed to build successfully, but I suspect I have something wrong with my binaryPath in .detoxrc?

- **react-native: 0.64.1**
- **detox: 18.22.1**

**.detoxrc.json**

```
 {
      "testRunner": "jest",
      "runnerConfig": "e2e/config.json",
      "skipLegacyWorkersInjection": true,
      "apps": {
        "ios": {
          "type": "ios.app",
          "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/myappname.app",
          "build": "xcodebuild -workspace ios/myappname.xcworkspace -configuration Release -scheme myappname id=ED0F3373-A57D-481B-86DA-D87007C00F85 -sdk iphonesimulator"
        }
      },
      "devices": {
        "simulator": {
          "type": "ios.simulator",
          "device": {
            "type": "iPhone 12"
          }
        }
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ios": {
          "device": "simulator",
          "app": "ios"
        }
      }
    }
```

**config.json**

```
{
    "maxWorkers": 1,
    "testEnvironment": "./environment",
    "testRunner": "jest-circus/runner",
    "testTimeout": 5000,
    "testNamePattern": "**.spec.js",
    "reporters": ["detox/runners/jest/streamlineReporter"],
    "verbose": true
}
```

react-native app running in iOS Simulator. `detox test -c ios` leads to:

*detox[72935] ERROR: [APP_UNREACHABLE] Detox can't seem to connect to the test app(s)!
HINT:
The test app might have crashed prematurely, or has had trouble setting up the connection.
Refer to our troubleshooting guide, for full details: > https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.RunningTests.md#tests-execution-hangs*

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me running on M1 Apple Silicon—fixed it by downgrading to 17.14.9

Comment: Thanks @Stepanie Chau. I'll give that I try when I have some time.